# How to place Firefox/Thunderbird password manager files on TrueCrypt volume?

Tags: passwords, thunderbird, truecrypt, firefox

I don't want enter master password in Firefox/Thunderbird everytime. I've got an idea to place the password manager files (`key3.db` and `signons.sqlite` -- or just one of them) on the TrueCrypt volume. I don't want to encrypt whole Firefox/Thunderbird profile, because I will lost the ability of diff backups (e.g. Previous versions in Windows) of the profile.

I have tried to use symlinks for that however it did not work. (Firefox after moving `key3.db` to a TrueCrypt volume and replacing it with symlink did not show any password.)

Can I specify somewhere that `key3.db` or `signons.sqlite` are located elsewhere?

UPDATE: When I would encrypt whole drive, then I will have to encrypt whole backups -- that I do not want to -- if something wrong happens to me, nobody can access the backups; or I can just forgot master password to backups. Currently, I am backuping everything unencrypted and also the small TrueCrypt file with passwords, keys, etc. -- if I loose the password to this TrueCrypt file, just passwords will be lost, but not my data.

CLARIFICATION: I do not want to backup passwords unencrypted.

Comment: You could just use Truecrypt to encrypt your drive?

Comment: An alternative would be to install [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) & [Thunderbird Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable) inside a TrueCrypt volume. It might be the easiest, so you can't forget to decrypt the databases. Performance may suffer, but I am not sure.

Comment: See my update ...

Comment: Have you tried symbolic links? I believe they can work across separate drives/volumes.

Comment: Yes, see the second paragraph.

Comment: Firefox plays some funny games with the DB.  I think they copy the DB on open then rewrite it on close, rather than using the DB "in place", so symbolic links and other such tricks don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you encrypt the entire drive using TrueCrypt, then you can backup your data from the running OS (i.e. truecrypt image has been supplied with password and is open/accessible) on a separate disk/DVD etc=> result: unencrypted backups, safe Thunderbird.
Of course, if you're using image-based backup (a la Norton Ghost) of an offline system, that wouldn't work...

Wondering why the symlinks didn't work - they should be transparant.

Comment: Because then the Thunderbird passwords will be unencrypted in the backups.

Comment: I didn't get that part from your question. Might be a good idea to edit your question: you don't want your keys backed up unencrypted, but don't care (or do you?) that your keys won't get backed up...

Comment: Ok, the question is updated.